# default parameters without name in c ++

Tags: c++, parameters, default

Consider the functions:

```
void foo(int a = 3)//named default parameter
void foo1(int = 3)//unnamed default parameter
```

I understand the need of the first function.(The value of "a" is 3 and it can be used in the program).
But the 2nd function(which is not an error) has 3 initialized to nothing. How exactly do i use this value , if i can use this value...

Comment: You normally put default parameters in the declaration. Often times you'll have both a declaration and a definition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does C++ code missing a formal argument name in a function definition compile without warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319663/why-does-c-code-missing-a-formal-argument-name-in-a-function-definition-compil). The default parameter makes no difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In function declaration/definition, a parameter may have or have not a name, this also applies to a parameter with default value.

But to use a parameter inside a function, a name must be provided.

Normally when declare a function with default parameter

```
// Unnamed default parameter. 
void foo1(int = 3);
```

In function definition

```
void foo1(int a)
{
   std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Then you can call

```
foo1();   // the same as call foo1(3)
foo1(2);
```

Comment: Yep. Though whether this is "A Good Idea" is completely subjective.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the 2nd declaration very useful when declaring an empty virtual method of a base class

```
virtual void doSomething(bool = false) {};
```

I don't want to make it pure virtual since in many derived classes I don't want to re-implement it, so I leave it empty in the base class.
But I need the default value `false` when implementing this method in some other derived classes.

```
virtual void doSomething(bool en = false) {};
```

This is not wrong but the compiler gives the unused parameter warning

Answer (score 0):

In both cases **3** is assigned to an `int` variable that will be determined on function definition.
so in later case - `void foo1(int = 3);` // 3 is being assigned to an `int` - as at declaration variable name is not required

you can relate this to - `void fun(int,int);`  **NOTE: not from default arguments point of view but from function declaration point of view**

// here we have declared two `int` variables and its not compulsory to give its name at function declaration time.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @chethan - `void foo1(int = 3){ }` is valid in function definition also, but then again whats the use of **doing something that you can't use later on (inside function body)**.
for ex:

```
void foo1 (int a, int =2)
{
// do something
// here you wont be able to use your second argument if you haven't gave it any name
}
```

so I think its pointless "Not to give argument name in function definition".

Comment: void foo1(int = 3) is possible even in definition.